# Cherry framework - Overriding function in template-general.php

Tags: theme-development

In wordpress Cherry framework, I am trying to edit template-general.php file functions, but it's different not able to do so. I tried to follow this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-your-child-theme--cms-22623), but does not help.

[Link for Cherry framework](http://www.cherryframework.com/) to download file structure is: *cherryframework4\lib\functions\template-general.php*

I am trying to override below function:

```
function cherry_get_site_logo( $location = 'header' ) {
    $logo_class = array();

    switch ( $location ) {
        case 'header':
            $type         = cherry_get_option( 'logo-type', 'text' );
            $logo_img_ids = cherry_get_option( 'logo-image-path', false );
            $tag          = is_front_page() ? 'h1' : 'h2';
            $logo_class[] = 'site-title';
            $logo_class[] = $type . '-logo';
            $link_class   = '';
            break;

        case 'footer':
            $type         = cherry_get_option( 'footer-logo-type', 'text' );
            $logo_img_ids = cherry_get_option( 'footer-logo-image-path', false );
            $tag          = 'div';
            $logo_class[] = 'cherry-footer-logo';
            $logo_class[] = $type . '-logo';
            $link_class   = 'footer-logo-link';
            break;

        default:
            $tag          = 'div';
            $logo_class[] = $location . '-logo';
            $link_class   = '';
            break;
    }

    $logo_class = apply_filters( 'cherry_logo_classes', $logo_class, $location );
    $logo_class = array_unique( $logo_class );
    $logo_class = array_map( 'sanitize_html_class', $logo_class );

    if ( 'image' == $type && false != $logo_img_ids ) {

        $images = explode( ',', $logo_img_ids );

        if ( count( $images ) > 1 ) {
            $logo_content = cherry_get_retina_logo( $images );
        } else {

            $img = wp_get_attachment_url( $images[0] );

            $logo_image_format = apply_filters(
                'cherry_logo_image_format',
                '<a href="%1$s" rel="home"><img src="%2$s" alt="%3$s"></a>',
                $location
            );

            $logo_content = sprintf( $logo_image_format, home_url( '/' ), esc_url( $img ), get_bloginfo( 'title' ) );
        }

    } else {
        $logo_content = cherry_get_site_link( $link_class );
    }

    $logo = $logo_content ? sprintf( '<%3$s class="%1$s">%2$s</%3$s>', join( ' ', $logo_class ), $logo_content, $tag ) : '';

    return apply_filters( 'cherry_get_site_logo', $logo, $location );
}
```

Anyone come across this? Help me find this problem.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: as i said ,, i followed http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-your-child-theme--cms-22623 this link ... in that link there are three ways of overriding , i tried all those but no effect change from child theme... actually function format i have doesnt match those code in that tutsplus link

Comment: tutsplus link explained abt 1) if function exists 2) priority override function 3) filter/action/hook removing fns ... these things are not in this function so i dont know how to override

Comment: there is a filter at the end `cherry_get_site_logo` why not just hook into that?

Comment: i tried like this                                                                                 function remove_cherry_get_site_logo($location = 'header') {
 $logo = $logo_content ? sprintf( '<%3$s class="%1$s">%2$s</%3$s>', join( ' ', $logo_class ), $logo_content, $tag ) : '';
   return remove_filter('cherry_get_site_logo', $logo, $location );
}
add_filter('init','cherry_get_site_logo', $logo, $location );

Comment: undefined logo variable came after i did it in my functions.php (child folder) ...

Comment: Thanks for letting us know what you tried. Makes it much easier to know how to help you. I've posted an answer along the lines of what @majick suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although overriding the function in a child theme is often a good way to go, it looks like this theme doesn't set that up with this particular function (because they're not checking if `function_exists()` first, before redefining it - which will cause an error).

However, they have given you a way of overriding it with filters.

At the bottom of their function, everything they return is being run through the `cherry_get_site_logo` filter.

**Everytime you see `apply_filters()` being run in someone else's code, this is something you can hook into** :)

To hook into this, you need to add your own filter function. In your function, you can either change their output (eg. through something like `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()` to replace parts of it), or you can simply ignore what they've done and provide your own output (which I understand is what you're after).

So in this case, to override the output of their function, you just need to:

```
add_filter("cherry_get_site_logo", "wpse_226159_site_logo");

function wpse_226159_site_logo($logo, $location){
    $logo = "This is my overriden logo";
    return $logo;
}
```

This will completely replace their logo output with the text `This is my overriden logo`. Obviously replace that with whatever you like.

This code goes in your child theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: you are great Tim . in this i just wanted to change a variable $tag in switch case "header".. from is_front_page() ? 'h1' : 'h2'; to is_front_page() ? 'h1' : 'h1'; .. how can i change that ? i tried to put only switch case alone in my function but nothing comes in html.. when i put whole code inside my function to replace just $tag, some undefined prob comes.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Now firstly, you didn't mention that in your original question - it helps if you ask everything relevant at first. Secondly, I can't help with "some undefined prob" - an error is trying to tell you what to fix; it's not a reason to ignore a solution. In your case you need to copy the entire function and change the bit you want to change. If there's an error, work out what that is telling you. Feel free to edit your question and add the details if you need to and I can edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Also, the reason they use h1 on the front page and h2 elsewhere is for HTML5 semantics and SEO: there should only ever be one h1 on a page, and on subpages the h1 is usually elsewhere with the title of the page in it. On the home page a common technique is to make the logo the h1 - the name of the site.

Comment: Tim , the reason i posted generally for overriding is , there are many functions like that so i asked generally and i thought i can work around that $tag variable easily but it isn't so asked you . Secondly i mentioned i got undefined prob because informed you that i tried with these. Basically im a html developer so programitically im lacking.

Comment: I know they used for seo purpose but i want that logo to be covered with both h1 in all pages .. so i dont know how to override that in switch case . Anyway thanks a lot Tim . Im struggling to override many functions in this theme framework . But patiently getting results one by one :)

Comment: No worries. Feel free to ask additional questions if you're having trouble with certain errors etc :)